# Insert missing values from RegEx into SQLite3

Tags: python, regex, sqlite, urllib2, missing-data

I've parsed several webpages using urllib/regex and saved the information (app. 10 variables) to SQLite3 from Python. Some of the information is missing for some webpages, so RegEx did not return anything in that case. After I've saved all information to sqlite, I got only the data sets, where all columns are non-missing values. How can I save the data sets with missing values to sqlite?

My database has to look like this:

```
apple pier cherry
 2    3     5
 1          4
      2     7
 5    4     6
 1
 2    3     7
```

My code:

```
for page in webpages:
    apples = findall(r'some regex',str(page))
    piers = findall(r'some regex',str(page))
    cherries = findall(r'some regex',str(page))

    for apple, pier, cherry in zip(apples, piers, cherries):
        c.execute('''insert into sometable (apple, pier, cherry) values(?,?,?)''',(apple, pier, cherry))
```

Comment: `cherrys` == `cherries`?

Comment: You called your database table `table`?

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the names of the variables from my original code to paste it here. I haven't seen that mistake.

Comment: No, I have changed the name for the Sqlite-table and names for the variables to paste it here to make everything look simple. It is no the syntax error that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

pass empty string as params to bind..

```
cur.execute("insert into table values ('asd',3,'','%s','%s')",('asdf','dd'));
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I must admit I did not understand the answer. I am really new to python. How do I assign the empty string as a parameter? What is the column names and parameters here?('asd',3,'','%s','%s')